# double quote string python

Tags: python, string

I have a string of the following form

```
'"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'
```

I need to tease out the sub-strings in double quotes, so '08770' and 'tykjkj'.

How should I do it in python?

Comment: Why not 'asdsadjieere'?

Comment: Judging by the answers, this question was about 15% clear on what was needed.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was, "teasing out" is what I mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'""(.*?)""', '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"')
['O8770', 'tykjkj']
```

Comment: That may be, but this is the only answer that actually gives exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: I agree, I like the answer Ben!

Comment: I guess the question was actually to extract strings between _pairs_ of double quotes, and without two matches sharing a pair of double quotes.

Comment: Yes, @Ben is correct that his output matches the OP's expected output. Most of the other answers do "tease out the sub-strings in double quotes." Ben wins because he *didn't* do that. He teased out sub-strings in *double* double quotes. The question was ambiguous, and he kept his eye on the prize!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously from the many answers, there are a lot of ways to do this. The trick is to "clean up" or "map" the initial string into something that can be readily separated, for example by the string `split()` method.

```
>>> s = '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'
>>> s.replace('"', '\t').split()
['asfdfdfds', 'O8770', 'asdsadjieere', 'tykjkj', 'ldkflskfd']
```

The choice of *how* to map the original string is dependent on what kind of strings you might get. Will they all have balanced quotes? What kind of whitespace or other characters might they include? How might real-world data be dirty / inconsistent with your basic parsing assumptions? Because every way to can try to parse / split the string is dependent on *some* assumptions.

Comment: The initial string doesn't really have to be cleaned up - `split()` can split on more than just whitespace.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes `split()` is quite versatile. But consider: Your answer uses `strip('"')` before it calls `split('""')`. That `strip` call? You're cleaning up the initial string into something that can then be conveniently split. QED.

Answer (score 0):

This works from the command line interpreter.

```
s = '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'
s.split('\"')
```

.

```
result:
['', 'asfdfdfds', '', 'O8770', '', 'asdsadjieere', '', 'tykjkj', '', 'ldkflskfd', '']
```

Comment: you don't need the escape, and you should split on 2 double quotes - `s.split('""')`

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'
mystring.strip('"').split('""')
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: It takes the string, removes the leading and trailing double quotes, then creates a list out of what's left delimited by pairs of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the string.split function with argument " gives you the substrings.

```
'"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'.split('"')
```

result:

```
['', 'asfdfdfds', '', 'O8770', '', 'asdsadjieere', '', 'tykjkj', '', 'ldkflskfd', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vals = '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'.split('\"')
print [val for val in vals if val]
```

Comment: You can replace `if val != ''` with `if val`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression

```
import re
string = '"asfdfdfds""O8770""asdsadjieere""tykjkj""ldkflskfd"'
print re.findall('".+?"', string)
```